# EF : order by 2 fields when they are not null

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have an entity with fields:

```
public partial class Load 
{
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdatedOn { get; set; }
}
```

I have to order records (DESC) by following way:
If UpdatedOn has value then "look at" this value, else look at CreatedOn value. How to do it?

Comment: .OrderBy(x=>x.UpdateOn).ThenBy(x=>x.CreatedOn)

Comment: @SinanBARAN it will sort created on inside the same UpdatedOn

Comment: You can do it using LINQ, if statement and so on. What have you tried and where you failed to accomplish your goal? I don't want to post a duplicate of code that you already tried.

Comment: @OlegSh Thank you for warning me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **`??`** operator is called the null-coalescing operator. It returns the left-hand operand if the operand is not null; otherwise it returns the right hand operand
[look here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator)

```
 items.OrderBy(x => x.UpdatedOn ?? x.CreatedOn);
```

OR

```
 items.OrderByDescending(x => x.UpdatedOn ?? x.CreatedOn);
```

Comment: yes of cource. sql output ORDER BY COALESCE([x].[UpdatedOn], [x].[CreatedOn])